# Finding the right equation for alpha

Tags: polynomials

If alpha is the repeated root of $\ p(x)=x^3+3ax^2+3bx+c=0$ then how do I check whether alpha is a root of $x^2+2ax+b=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $p'(\alpha)=0$. Can you take it up from here?

Answer (score 1):

A repeated root of $p$ is also a root of $p'$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$x^3+3ax^2+3bx+c=(x-p)^2(x-q)$$

$$\iff x^3+3ax^2+3bx+c=x^3+x^2(-2p-q)+(p^2-q)x+p^2q$$

$2p+q=-3a\iff q=-3a-2p\ \ \ \ (1)$

$p^2+2pq=3b\ \ \ \ (2)$

Set the value of $q$ in $(2)$ from $(1)$